# obtaining an image in Pstricks

Tags: pstricks

How do I draw [this image](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Law_of_Quadratic_Reciprocity) in PStricks:

[image]

I know to draw the axis but not sure how to name the points and all.

Comment: Is TikZ, Metapost and Asymptote allowed for drawing? Have you tried to draw it by yourself? If you have, please post your code as a starting point for others.

Comment: @Malipivo I dont know tikz metapost and all. So its better that i get a pstricks command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a code in psTricks:

```
 \documentclass[pdf, x11names, dvipsnames]{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc }
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}%
\newpsobject{bluedot}{psdot}{linecolor=RoyalBlue3, dotsize=4pt}

\begin{document}

\psset{llx=-5mm,lly=-5mm,urx=5mm,ury=5mm, arrowinset=0, %
    psgrid, gridwidth=0.6pt, gridcolor=RoyalBlue3, griddots=10, subgriddiv=1}%

\begin{pspicture*}(-1.5,-1.5)(9.6,8.5)
    \psaxes[labels=none, ticks=none](0,0)(-1.5,-1.5)(9.6,8.5)
    \psgrid[gridlabels = 8pt](0,0)(-1.5,-1.5)(9.6,8.5)
    \multido{\i=-1 + 1}{11}{\multido{\I=-1 + 1}{10}{\bluedot(\i, \I)}}
    \psline[linestyle = dashed, linewidth=0.4pt]{*-*}(0,6.5)(8.5,6.5)(8.5,0)
    \bluedot(0,6.5)\bluedot(8.5,0)\uput[l](0,6.5){$ \bigl (0,\mfrac q2\bigr) $}\uput{0.3}[d](8.5,0){$\bigl (\mfrac p2,0\bigr)$}
    \dotnodes(0,0){O}(8.5,6.5){A}
    \ncline{O}{A}\naput[npos=0.325, nrot=:U, labelsep=2pt]{$ y = \mfrac qp x$}
    \uput[r](A){$\bigl (\mfrac p2,\mfrac q2\bigr)$}\uput{0.33}[-120](O){$ (0,0) $}
    \psline{<->}(6.25,0.04)(6.25,3.96)
    \bluedot(6.25,4)\bluedot(6.25,0)\rput[bl](6.25,4){$ \bigl(k, \mfrac qp k\bigr) $}\uput{0.4}[d](6.25,0){$ (k, 0) $}
    \rput(2.5,4.5){\Large\bfseries\sffamily A}
    \rput(4.5,1.5){\Large\bfseries\sffamily B}
    \multido{\i = 1 + 1}{4}{\psdot(6,\i)}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]